# Trying to bootstrap gcc/glibc toolchain

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc, bootstrapping

I'm trying to bootstrap the gcc/glibc toolchain. It always fails to build failures. I have been trying dozens of times with different methods.

Here is how I have been trying to bootstrap:

```
path:
export PATH=/home/defer/dev/linux/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/gcc-bin/4.8.2

binutils:
../configure --prefix=/home/defer/dev/linux --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --with-sysroot=/home/defer/dev/linux --with-lib-path=/home/defer/dev/linux/lib --disable-nls --disable-werror

gcc stage1:
../configure --target=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/defer/dev/linux --with-sysroot=/home/defer/dev/linux --with-newlib --without-headers --with-native-system-header-dir=/home/defer/dev/linux/include --disable-nls
--disable-shared --disable-multilib --disable-decimal-float --disable-threads --disable-libatomic --disable-libgomp --disable-libitm --disable-libmudflap --disable-libquadmath --disable-libsanitizer --disable-libssp --disable-libstdc++-v3 --enable-languages=c,c++

linux headers:
make INSTALL_HDR_PATH=/home/defer/dev/linux headers_install

glibc:
../configure --prefix=/home/defer/dev/linux --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --disable-profile --enable-kernel=2.6.32 --with-headers=/home/defer/dev/linux/include libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes libc_cv_ctors_header=yes libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes
```

Here are errors I get while building glibc:

```
a - ns_netint.os
a - ns_ttl.os
a - ns_print.os
a - ns_samedomain.os
a - ns_date.os
cd /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv && /home/defer/dev/linux/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ar cruv libnss_dns_pic.a dns-host.os dns-network.os dns-canon.os
cd /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv && /home/defer/dev/linux/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ar cruv libanl.a gai_cancel.o gai_error.o gai_misc.o gai_notify.o gai_suspend.o getaddrinfo_a.o
a - dns-host.os
a - dns-network.os
a - dns-canon.os
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc   -shared -static-libgcc -Wl,-O1  -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/home/defer/dev/linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  -B/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/csu/  -Wl,--version-script=/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/libresolv.map -Wl,-soname=libresolv.so.2 -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both  -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/math -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/elf -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/dlfcn -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nss -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nis -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/rt -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/crypt -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nptl -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/math:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/elf:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/dlfcn:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nss:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nis:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/rt:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/crypt:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nptl -o /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv.so -T /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/shlib.lds /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/csu/abi-note.o -Wl,--whole-archive /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv_pic.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/elf/interp.os  -Wl,--start-group /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/libc.so /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--end-group
a - gai_cancel.o
a - gai_error.o
a - gai_misc.o
a - gai_notify.o
a - gai_suspend.o
a - getaddrinfo_a.o
cd /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv && /home/defer/dev/linux/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/4.8.2/../../../../x86_64-pc-linux-gnu/bin/ar cruv libanl_pic.a gai_cancel.os gai_error.os gai_misc.os gai_notify.os gai_suspend.os getaddrinfo_a.os
a - gai_cancel.os
a - gai_error.os
a - gai_misc.os
a - gai_notify.os
a - gai_suspend.os
a - getaddrinfo_a.os
x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-gcc   -shared -static-libgcc -Wl,-O1  -Wl,-z,defs -Wl,-dynamic-linker=/home/defer/dev/linux/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2  -B/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/csu/  -Wl,--version-script=/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/libanl.map -Wl,-soname=libanl.so.1 -Wl,-z,combreloc -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,--hash-style=both  -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/math -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/elf -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/dlfcn -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nss -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nis -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/rt -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/crypt -L/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nptl -Wl,-rpath-link=/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/math:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/elf:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/dlfcn:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nss:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nis:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/rt:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/crypt:/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nptl -o /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libanl.so -T /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/shlib.lds /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/csu/abi-note.o -Wl,--whole-archive /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libanl_pic.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/elf/interp.os /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nptl/libpthread_nonshared.a /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/nptl/libpthread.so  -Wl,--start-group /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/libc.so /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/libc_nonshared.a -Wl,--as-needed /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/elf/ld.so -Wl,--no-as-needed -Wl,--end-group
rm -f /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libanl.so.1.new
/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(ns_print.os): In function `__GI_ns_sprintrrf':
/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/ns_print.c:99: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/ns_print.c:728: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(gethnamaddr.os): In function `getanswer':
/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:180: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:483: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(gethnamaddr.os): In function `__GI_res_gethostbyname2':
/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:510: undefined reference to `__stack_chk_guard'
/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv_pic.a(gethnamaddr.os):/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/resolv/gethnamaddr.c:636: more undefined references to `__stack_chk_guard' follow
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
/bin/sh ../scripts/rellns-sh /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libanl.so /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libanl.so.1.new
../Makerules:438: recipe for target '/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv.so' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libresolv.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
mv -f /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libanl.so.1.new /home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/glibc-build/resolv/libanl.so.1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19/resolv'
Makefile:213: recipe for target 'resolv/others' failed
make[1]: *** [resolv/others] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/defer/dev/linux/src/glibc-2.19'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2

real    3m23.747s
user    9m57.851s
sys    1m21.334s
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved the problem. Gentoo GCC had stack smash protection on by default.

I had to use:

```
CFLAGS="-O2 -fno-stack-protector" ../configure --prefix=/home/defer/dev/linux --host=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --build=x86_64-pc-linux-gnu --disable-profile --enable-kernel=2.6.32 --with-headers=/home/defer/dev/linux/include libc_cv_forced_unwind=yes libc_cv_ctors_header=yes libc_cv_c_cleanup=yes
```